# Plot with Legends and Markers

Tags: plotting, legending

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating legends for plots with multiple lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines)

I must say I have seen a couple of similar questions but they were not addressing my specific problem.

Level one: I'm trying to combine two plots, a `ListPlot` of "data" say, and a plot of the "theory". Level two: the `ListPlot` has a legend so I should use `ShowLegend[data,theory,....]`, ok fine. The problem now comes at level three: quite obviously the `ListPlot` ("data") has markers (disks, boxes, and diamonds which are the `Automatic` ones). How can I reproduce those exact markers with the `ShowLegend` directive?

István Zachar's answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3518/using-plotlegends-with-show-messes-up-the-graphics) explicitly mentions that producing a legend for a plot with markers is more complex.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If possible, you should always include a small example which everyone can try to see your problem.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines/4028#4028), where your questions have been addressed. First off, `PlotLegends` is a terrible package and using it will only result in untold misery and headache. Jens has developed an excellent legending system, which you can get from the linked question. It also handles cases with markers easily. Please give that a try.