# Plot functions over different domains with legend

Tags: plotting

I have two functions which I'd like to plot over different domains, and combine them into a single plot, with a legend included.  If it weren't for the legend, I'd simply use `Show`.  However, I have issues with Mathematica's new `ShowLegend` even in the most trivial case, so I'm not sure quite how to go about this.  There are a few posts about using `ShowLegend` within `Show` but I had trouble making sense of them, and I'm wondering if my simple case, there's an easier way.  An example that will suffice is

```
F[x_] := Sqrt[4 - x^2];
G[x_] := 9 - x^2;
Plot[F[x], {x, 0, 2}]
Plot[G[x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

with the resulting plot being over the full range `{x, 0 ,3}`.

Comment: `Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

Comment: Young's solution is perfect here, but even if you didn't use that there's no reason to use `ShowLegend`:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100997/9490

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[4 - x^2]
g[x_] := 9 - x^2
```

You can do it Young's way, which works well for your example functions, as JasonB noted in a comment.

```
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotLegends -> {f[x], g[x]}]
```

[image: plot1]

Or you can fake it with `Inset`, which will give you more control.

```
With[
    {colors = ColorData[97],
     rowF = 
       Row[
         {Graphics[{Thick, #1, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]},
            AspectRatio -> 1/6, ImageSize -> 30],
          "  ",
          #2}] &},
  With[
      {inset =
         Panel[Column[{rowF @@ {colors[1], f[x]}, rowF @@ {colors[2], g[x]}}]]},
    Show[
      Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> colors[1]],
      Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> colors[2]],
      Graphics[Inset[inset, Scaled[{1, 1}], {Right, Top}]],
      PlotRange -> All]]]
```

[image: plot2]

Clearly, doing it with `Inset` is more work, but it gives you complete control over how your legend looks and where it is placed.

Comment: You don't *have* to use Inset: `Legended[
 Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> colors[1]], 
  Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> colors[2]], PlotRange -> All],
 Placed[LineLegend[97, {f[x], g[x]}, LegendFunction -> Panel], {Right,
    Top}]]`

Comment: @BrettChampion. Looks like good answer. You should post it. I haven't learned all these new-fangled things like `Legended`. My answer shows the the way I've been doing this sort of thing since long before `Legended` appeared.

Answer (score 2):

Adding legends to two distinct `Plot[]`s doesn't prevent `Show` from combining them appropriately:

```
F[x_] := Sqrt[4 - x^2]
G[x_] := 9 - x^2

pos = {Right, Top};
Show[Plot[F[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{F}, pos], PlotStyle -> Red],
     Plot[G[x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{G}, pos]], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Thanks!  Can one easily place the legend in the bulk of the figure this way?  I notice now that `LegendPosition` doesn't work, even if the two locations are the same.  Maybe this is a command from an old Mathematica

Comment: @spietro Non-numeric position arguments in `Placed` keeps the legend within the bulk. See the edit.